# How can I get a more distinct bar graph in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have ploted a graph using matplotlib in jupyter notebook. I have 3 bars with a very small difference between them. I want to plot a graph that is accurate and shows the difference between the values clearly. I have attached a picture of a graph that I want and my graph

My Code:

```
pt.bar(['Treated' , 'Untreated' , 'Control'] , [treated_dataset['Pos 1'].mean() , untreated_dataset['Pos 2'].mean() , control_dataset['Pos 3'].mean()] , color = 'blue')
```

My Graph :

[image: My Graph]

The Graph that I want:

[image: Goal Graph]

Comment: You can browse the [gallery](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/index.html) for some ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can zoom by setting the limits of the abscissa with `pt.set_ylim((90, 97))`.